# Excel VBA SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, access-denied, not-exists

I cant solve the Title error and I need help.

Im trying to connect to my Server per SQL Native Client Aliase.

I can connect to the Server with SQL Server Managment Studio but not with Excel VBA Programm.

I can ping Server IP adress.

The Programm works fine on other PCs so there is no problem with the code.

I have Added Firewall Rules for the TCP Ports (Standard and Aliase).

I tired to start the Programm as Administrator.

I tried to switch off the Antivirus.

Im not sure what else I already tried, so I need help.

Thank you for your Attention.

**CODE:**

```
Private Cn As New ADODB.Connection

Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
            ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
```

Comment: Showing us your code would be a start.

Comment: are they both 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: As I wrote, the Programm works fine on other PCs, so there cant be a Code Error.

Im sorry braX, what do you mean with both?

Comment: added code as you asked

Comment: And yet, your addition helps no one understand exactly what values you use to connect to your server instance. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server) is basic connectivity problem solver.